# Solder Core Size

Tags: soldering, core

Pardon the very simple question, but I am a beginner looking to buy my first good solder for through hole work.  I was looking at a 63/37 Kester 285 or AIM RMA, but one thing I’m curious about is the core size.  Most of the products I’m looking at have anything from a 1.8 to 3.3% core, but I’m not sure what I should be getting.

If any of you could offer some advice, I’d be most grateful.

Comment: For a beginner, especially doing through-hole work, it really doesn't matter all that much, so don't stress yourself out over it.

Comment: This is primarily opinion based and will most likely be closed. But other than that. I prefer 0.6mm solder with 2.2% flux. I also primarily use and prefer lead free solder. Please read the rules for asking questions.

Comment: Whatever flux you end up using, do make sure to arrange for some airflow to keep the soldering fumes away from your eyes and lungs.

Comment: People, before you comment on or answer this question, note that it is about the percentage of core (flux) in the solder, not about the gauge (size) of the solder itself.

Comment: I think for beginner/hobby soldering, more flux is better, but if you are applying flux to surfaces before you solder, as you should, the amount of flux in your solder won't matter as much.  I imagine more flux *in* the solder would help more at higher skill levels and for tasks like pre-tinning wires or components, as the pre-fluxing stage could be skipped.

Comment: Why in the name of all that's holy does everyone want to flood everything in flux?

Comment: @JRE Because it solves a lot of problems at the expense of extra clean up when you don't know what you're doing and beginners can't tell if their technique, tools, or lack of flux is the problem so it removes a variable. They don't know what how solder is supposed to behave yet to know something is not wetting properly. Also, you burn up a lot of it if you're inexperienced and repeatedly have to rework the same joint. If you're experienced enough to do it in one go then you need almost none.

Answer (score 0):

what percentage of flux you should take depends on how much flux you are likely to need.

I cant guess at the work you are going to do, but be aware

More flux means more smoke and more mess.

Not enough flux makes it hard to solder.

Smaller parts need a higher flux to solder ratio because the solder volume to surface-area ratio is higher.

having some extra flux on-hand can be useful for tricky jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Its mostly up to you, it really depends on how much flux you like on your board. This makes it more difficult to clean. If you normally solder and find that you don't have enough flux to wet the solder, then get a larger core size.

I'm not a fan of flux, I apply it with a syringe and a very fine tip to make sure I get as little of it on the board, then I have less to clean off later on.

Answer (score 0):

This question is most likely to be closed for two reasons: asks for opinions **and** asks for product recommendations.

That said: I'll give you my opinion.  Many others here may disagree.

1) For most of the work that I do, I prefer Kester 63/37 lead-based solder with their type 44 RA flux.  This solder does leave flux residue on the board but it does not affect any of the circuits that I work with.  Datasheet says core is "66" which is 3.3% flux.

2) Diameter depends on what you are doing.  Generally, I prefer to use solder as thick as I can get away with.

2a) I'm perfectly happy using 0.040" or 0.050" diameter for working on through-hole circuit boards.  The solder feeds easily but it is extremely easy to control the amount of solder on the joint.

2b) Larger-sized SMD devices: 0.031" diamter is good.

2c) Smaller-sized SMD devices: 0.015" works well.

2d) Larger connectors such as 3-pin XLR audio connectors: 0.050" or 0.062" diameter is my choice.  Higher-density XLR connectors require smaller diameter solder: 4 to 6 pin connectors are easily soldered with 0.040" or 0.050" solder.  7-pin XLR connectors are best soldered with 0.031" diameter solder.

In general, match the diameter of the solder to the task at hand.

Flux choices:  I'll refer to Kester part numbers because that is what I remember.  We also use AIM solder but I don't recall those numbers.

1) General purpose or first-time building: Kester type 44 flux.  Decent cleaning ability and flux residue doesn't affect anything other than high-impedance circuits.

2) Rework, where the PCB pad has already had solder on it.  Kester type 285 or 245 Mildly-activated flux.  Doesn't clean leads or pads very well but usually not a problem for re-work.

3) Production soldering, where you are building many boards. Kester type 331 (roll solder) or type AZ2331 liquid flux for wave-solder.  This is an extremely active flux that cleans better than almost anything else that I have used.  However, it **MUST** be cleaned from the board immediately after soldering.  It is electrically-conductive and becomes corrosive if left on the board for more than several hours.

The beauty of this flux is that it is water-soluble.  Simply **thoroughly** wash the board both top and bottom under warm or hot running water, then blow dry.  Stop rinsing the board when all of the soap bubbles stop appearing.

The remaining ionic contamination is not measurable with the (decent) measuring instrument that I keep around.

Final note: many users prefer to use the thinnest solder possible.  There are several good reasons why this is NOT advisable.  The main reason, for me, is that because the solder is so thin, it takes far longer to feed the required amount of solder to the pad and lead than is necessary.

One of the key to not damaging circuit board pads and traces is to minimize the amount of time that the soldering iron is on the pad.  Using thicker solder allows you to get the required amount of solder onto the pad and still have enough dwell time to ensure a perfect solder joint without damaging the pad.